# If able to use both Frozen Rows and paginator in primeng table

Tags: angular6, primeng, primeng-table

I am new to primeng if have any possibility to use Frozen Rows and Paginator on primeng table. If possibility means can some tell how to handle table data with paginator( i.e If we fixed first page 5 records that five only will be display then next 5 with help of pagination).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [paginator]="true" property to enable pagination for table.
rows property defines the number of rows per page and pageLinks specify the number of page links to display

```
<p-table [paginator]="true" [rows]="5"  [pageLinks]="5" [rowsPerPageOptions]=" [5,10,15]">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i missed [pageLinks] property that is problem.